# Signalr supported platforms

Tags: signalr, windows-server

I am in a middle of migrating a one classic Azure VM (hosting a web app using Signalr) to an Azure resource manager scale set having multiple VMS with os Windows Server 2016.

Looking at Signalr documentation (https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/supported-platforms)  is seems that it support only Windows Server 2012.

I am using Signalr 2.2.0 .

I couldn't find any documentation saying that Signalr is supported on Windows Server 2016.

Does Windows Server 2016 supports Signalr?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does Windows Server 2016 supports Signalr?

Yes, because you can run .Net 4.5(+) on Server 2016 (I would think this would be obvious).  The following documentation was published in 2014, long before 2016 was released, so it's not going to mention future server versions explicitly.  It seems the only requirement is the ability to enable Web Sockets.

(for example asp.net 2.0 was released in 2005 and can be run on Server 2016)

https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/supported-platforms

Excerpt:

### Supported server operating systems

The SignalR server component can be hosted in the following server or client operating systems. Note that for SignalR to use WebSockets, Windows Server 2012 or Windows 8 is required (WebSocket can be used on Windows Azure Web Sites, as long as the site's .NET framework version is set to 4.5, and Web Sockets is enabled in the site's Configuration page).

- Windows Server 2012
- Windows Server 2008 r2
- Windows 8
- Windows 7
- Windows Azure
- Supported server .NET Framework version

SignalR 2 is only supported on .NET Famework 4.5. See the Recommended Updates section for updates that enhance reliability, compatibility, stability, and performance.

### Supported server IIS versions

When SignalR is hosted in IIS, the following versions are supported. Note that if a client operating system is used, such as for development (Windows 8 or Windows 7), full versions of IIS or Cassini should not be used, since there will be a limit of 10 simultaneous connections imposed, which will be reached very quickly since connections are transient, frequently re-established, and are not disposed immediately upon no longer being used. IIS Express should be used on client operating systems.

Also note that for SignalR to use WebSocket, IIS 8 or IIS 8 Express must be used, the server must be using Windows 8, Windows Server 2012, or later, and WebSocket must be enabled in IIS. For information on how to enable WebSocket in IIS, see IIS 8.0 WebSocket Protocol Support.

- IIS 8 or IIS 8 Express.
- IIS 7 and 7.5. Support for extensionless URLs is required.
- IIS must be running in integrated mode; classic mode is not supported. Message delays of up to 30 seconds may be experienced if IIS is run in classic mode using the Server-Sent Events transport.
- The hosting application must be running in full trust mode.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! What I was looking was more of an official statement from Microsoft . I am just afraid that something might go wrong on Windows Server 2016 and I have to revert . But I thing the easiest solution would be to give it a try :) .

Comment: So I spin a Windows Server 2016 machine on Azure and deployed a Signalr app built on .Net 4.5 . Everything is working ok so far , no issue noticed .

Comment: So, you do not mention Windows 10 Enterprise Edition.  Why not?

Comment: @CBrauer *Excerpt - take (a short extract) from a text*.  I am not an authority on the subject, I just noted the link and the text available with the relevant information specific to her request.  Since IIS runs on WIndows 10 EE, I would expect it to also work.